# Regex code is too long and inefficient. I want to make it better

Tags: python, regex, parsing, matching

Edit: Okay, my apologies because my first phrasing of the question over simplistic that the answers which are technically correct didn't work with my case, so I'll try to be as detailed as possible this time.

I am working on constructing a regex to capture a single or compound codes.
Each code would start with "H", "G", "EUH", or "AUG", followed by either three digits(H123) or three digits, a dot, and one digit. (H123.1).
First digit must not be a zero.

Each H code could be followed by one or more of these characters: "idDfF".(H231Df).
Each P code could be followed by one or more of these characters: "AEBDab".(P333a).
Each EUH code could be followed by "A".(EUH123A).

Example for compounds: H123Df+H234+H234.1+H342.1Fd, and P123.1+P555D
Spaces could be anywhere in the string except the 3 digits, those always follow each other with no spaces.
Dots or dashes could be before the extra characters at the end (H123-Df, H123.Df)

I need to match every compound or single code. Please note that in my previous try, I'd detect H567+H890+H654 correct but also H567 and H890 and H654, this is wrong. Once a set is matched, its inner codes shouldn't be treated as single codes anymore.

My current approach right now is actually 4 different regex codes, one for each set of codes. It mostly works (I guess) but it is very tedious and wouldn't work if another code is added to a compound and over all very unmaintainable with more complex stuff added to the regex.
Here's an example for the regex for the P codes.

```
`p = "P\s*\d{3}[.\s-]*[AEBDab]*\s*[+/]\s*P*\s*\d{3}[.\s-]*[AEBDab]*\s*[+/]\s*P*\s*\d{3}[.\s-]*[AEBDab]*|P\s*\d{3}[.\s-]*[AEBDab]*\s*[+/]\s*P*\s*\d{3}[.\s-][AEBDab]*|P\s*\d{3}[.\s-]*[AEBDab]*\s`"
```

As you can see, it's very long and inefficient, and to edit a minor thing would take so much time and be very prone to errors.

How can I achieve this in a better way? Is making 4 regex's better or just one for catching all formats of all 4 codes?

Edit:
A realistic version would look exactly like this:

```
text = "random text
H326random text H243Df+H546+H677-Drandom text
randomtext P234a+P333.Ddrandom text
someother randomtexts"

output = [H326, H243+H546+H677, H234+H333]
```

note: spaces are very random in the texts provided because they are PDF texts parsed with pdfminer library, it messes up the order and spaces very much, but it was the only library I found that could actually "read" all the 10k PDF files I have, other libraries would yield empty strings and or just read parts of the PDF.

Note: if you could explain your answer, because as I am working I'm always discovering new formats and I want to be able to edit the regex as I want.

Thank you!

Comment: Can you clarify what a realistic version of input would look like and what the output should look like?

Comment: I would suggest using patterns. You can learn more about them here: https://diveintopython3.problemsolving.io/regular-expressions.html

Comment: Not sure what you are after but maybe `X\d{3}(?:\+X\d{3})*` does help? See [this](https://regex101.com/r/8UV1jy/1)

Comment: Okay, so can X be any letter, or is it H? Your expression and input/output don't match now.

Comment: I put X as a placeholder for the alphabetical character, cause there are multiple I want to capture. H, P, G, etc.

Comment: Can you update your `realistic` version including the possible suffixes
(Df, [AEBDab], or A), dots or dashes before the suffixes, and possible
whitespaces in the string as a minimum complete test set?

Comment: @tshiono, yup, done.

Answer (score 5):

Something like this might work for you:

```py
import re

i = 'random text H326 H243+H546+H677 H234+H333 some other random texts X567+X890+X654'
capture_letters = 'HPGX'
regex = rf'[{capture_letters}]\d{{3}}(?:\+[{capture_letters}]\d{{3}})*'

print([i.group(0) for i in re.finditer(regex, i)])
```

Put whatever letters are valid starts to codes in the `capture_letters` string.

You can also use `A-Z` if any capital letter works.

Comment: This seems to be working well with my case at first try, but I'm still testing with different formats and corner cases. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

With your shown samples, could you please try following.

```
import re
value = 'X123 X234+X567 some intermixed text X567+X890+X654 some extra text'
regex = r'(([a-zA-Z]+\d{3}\+?){1,})'
print([key.group(0) for key in re.finditer(regex, value)])
```

Output will be as follows:

```
['X123', 'X234+X567', 'X567+X890+X654']
```

Answer (score 2):

So by your comments, it looks like you could use `re.findall` with the following pattern:

```
\b[HPGX]\d{3}(?:\+[HPGX]\d{3})*\b
```

See an online [demo](https://regex101.com/r/Zw8Xa5/1)

- `\b` - Word boundary.
- `[HPGX]` - A single character from mentioned character class.
- `\d{3}` - Three digits.
- `(?:` - Open non-capture group:

  - `\+` - A literal "+".
  - `[HPGX]` - A single character from mentioned character class.
  - `\d{3}` - Three digits.
  - `)*` - Close non-capture group and match it 0+ times (greedy).
- `\b` - Word boundary.

---

```
import re
txt = 'random text H326 H243+H546+H677 H234+H333 some other random texts'
lst = re.findall(r'\b[HPGX]\d{3}(?:\+[HPGX]\d{3})*\b', txt)
print(lst)
```

Prints:

```
['H326', 'H243+H546+H677', 'H234+H333']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify the regex with the `recursive regex` using the `regex`
(not `re`) module.

```
import regex

text = """random text
H326random text H243Df+H546+H677-Drandom text
randomtext P234a+P333.Ddrandom text
someother randomtexts"""

m = regex.finditer(r'(H\s*\d{3}[.\s-]*[idDfF]*|(?:AU)?G\s*\d{3}(?:\.\d)|P\s*\d{3}[.\s-]*[AEBDab]*|EUH\s*\d{3}\s*A?)(?:\+(?1))*', text)
print([i.group(0) for i in m])
```

Result:

```
['H326', 'H243Df+H546+H677-D', 'P234a+P333.D']
```

Explanations:

- The regex `(H\s*\d{3}[.\s-]*[idDfF]*|(?:AU)?G\s*\d{3}(?:\.\d)|P\s*\d{3}[.\s-]*[AEBDab]*|EUH\s*\d{3}\s*A?)` is a specification of the codes. If I'm not
  fully understanding the rules, it will be easy for you to fix the regex.
  The pattern is parenthesized and is re-used as `(?1)` in the following pattern.
- The regex `(?:\+(?1))*` is a cluster of a plus sign and the `(?1)`,
  a recursive regex defined above.
- The matched substring is referred as `group(0)`.